# Ethereum Wallet mining crash on test net

Tags: mist, mining, wallets

When I'm on test network I receive error after start mining, here following the logs:

```
I1231 13:39:56.291599 ethdb/database.go:83] Allotted 128MB cache and
1024 file handles to
C:\Users\boss\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum\testnet\chaindata I1231
13:39:56.668124 ethdb/database.go:176] closed
db:C:\Users\boss\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum\testnet\chaindata I1231
13:39:56.679130 node/node.go:176] instance:
Geth/v1.5.5-stable-ff07d548/windows/go1.7.4 I1231 13:39:56.679130
ethdb/database.go:83] Allotted 128MB cache and 1024 file handles to
C:\Users\boss\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum\testnet\chaindata I1231
13:39:57.211713 core/genesis.go:93] Genesis block already in chain.
Writing canonical number I1231 13:39:57.212713 eth/backend.go:280]
Successfully wrote custom genesis block:
41941023680923e0fe4d74a34bdac8141f2540e3ae90623718e47d66d1ca4a2d I1231
13:39:57.216721 eth/backend.go:191] Protocol Versions: [63 62],
Network Id: 3 I1231 13:39:57.217224 eth/backend.go:219] Chain config:
{ChainID: 3 Homestead: 0 DAO: <nil> DAOSupport: true EIP150: 0 EIP155:
10 EIP158: 10} I1231 13:39:57.224227 core/blockchain.go:219] Last
header: #253818 [069e8abc…] TD=58153388443067 I1231 13:39:57.224728
core/blockchain.go:220] Last block: #253818 [069e8abc…]
TD=58153388443067 I1231 13:39:57.224728 core/blockchain.go:221] Fast
block: #253818 [069e8abc…] TD=58153388443067 I1231 13:39:57.229231
eth/handler.go:119] blockchain not empty, fast sync disabled I1231
13:39:57.232732 p2p/server.go:342] Starting Server I1231
13:39:59.685651 p2p/discover/udp.go:227] Listening,
enode://f1ec2205b66db26c429a9169bef2d0b4d6a3f6d5eb5bd8831c352d48c5f3b88658348f61b3f2850704e7351264211d5945786f5055719aec976e093614f32058@[::]:30303
I1231 13:39:59.686646 p2p/server.go:610] Listening on [::]:30303 I1231
13:39:59.692649 node/node.go:341] IPC endpoint opened:
\\.\pipe\geth.ipc I1231 13:40:26.310023 eth/backend.go:475] Automatic
pregeneration of ethash DAG ON (ethash dir:
C:\Users\boss\AppData\Ethash) I1231 13:40:26.310023
miner/miner.go:136] Starting mining operation (CPU=1 TOT=2) I1231
13:40:26.310023 eth/backend.go:482] checking DAG (ethash dir:
C:\Users\boss\AppData\Ethash) I1231 13:40:26.312021
miner/worker.go:516] commit new work on block 253819 with 0 txs & 0
uncles. Took 1.9982ms I1231 13:40:26.312021
vendor/github.com/ethereum/ethash/ethash.go:259] 

Generating DAG for epoch 8 (size 1140849536)
(c307e5620454e771052a14bea2468aa36e4d01104c1bb0589fb96c692da7cebc)

panic: ethash_full_new IO or memory error

goroutine 1376 [running]: panic(0xc14fa0, 0x1715bd30)
  C:/go/src/runtime/panic.go:500 +0x331
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/ethereum/ethash.(*dag).generate.func1()
  C:/gopath/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/ethereum/ethash/ethash.go:273
+0x4d3 sync.(*Once).Do(0x174ba224, 0x1749bc10)  C:/go/src/sync/once.go:44 +0xcf
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/ethereum/ethash.(*dag).generate(0x174ba210)
  C:/gopath/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/ethereum/ethash/ethash.go:277
+0x3d github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/ethereum/ethash.(*Full).getDAG(0x15ccfc60, 0x3df7b, 0x0, 0x174ba210)
  C:/gopath/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/ethereum/ethash/ethash.go:333
+0xae github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/ethereum/ethash.(*Full).Search(0x15ccfc60, 0x1292c00, 0x174b2230, 0x17370dc0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
  C:/gopath/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/ethereum/ethash/ethash.go:338
+0x71 github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/miner.(*CpuAgent).mine(0x16d0db00,
0x161d1ce0, 0x17370dc0)
  C:/gopath/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/miner/agent.go:113
+0x147 created by github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/miner.(*CpuAgent).update
  C:/gopath/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/miner/agent.go:82
+0x11f
```

And I can't get it to work. I'm on windows 10 64 bit and using Ethereum Wallet 0.8.8. I've 8Gb of Ram and more than 200Gb free on hard disk.

I'm working on "real internet" and NOT on private network. I only want to mine something and try to deploy my contract and exchange something on test network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved using Mist instead of Ethereum Wallet, as suggested on this post:

[Trouble with Mist wallet 0.8.7 and 0.8.8](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10728/trouble-with-mist-wallet-0-8-7-and-0-8-8?rq=1)